# Writing a grammar that creates a specific language from a given grammar in Chomsky normal form

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

Given a grammar in Chomsky normal form that creates a language $L$ over alphabet $\Sigma$, that the letter z doesn't belong to $\Sigma$, without the empty string. I need to write a **context-free grammar** that creates the following language $L^\prime$:

$$L^\prime = \{a_1\mathtt{z}a_2\mathtt{z}a_3\mathtt{z}\ldots a_n\mathtt{z} \mid n \geq 1,\;\wedge\; \forall i, a_i\in \Sigma \; \wedge \; \exists b_1\ldots b_n\in\Sigma :a_1b_1\ldots a_nb_n\in L\}$$

(you can also see [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnUPZ.jpg) for L' definition)

So I think every rule A -> a in the given Chomsky normal form grammar should be changed to A -> az but I am not sure if this is enough.

Comment: Please consider learning how to [format mathematics on this site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It's not necessary to include images to make your question readable.

Comment: Changing the rule to $A\rightarrow a\mathtt{z}$ is not enough. The language $L^\prime$ consists of strings from $L$ where every other character has been replaced with $\mathtt{z}$. In contrast, your suggested change would make a language $L^{\prime\prime}$ consisting of strings from $L$ where $\mathtt{z}$ has been inserted in between every character, but no characters have been replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The language of strings from $L$ where every other symbol has been replaced with $\mathtt{\#}$.

You can do it by having each nonterminal symbol $A$ keep track of two more pieces of information: (1) Will $A$ become an even-length string or odd-length string? (2) Will $A$ start with $\mathtt{z}$ or some other character?

**Keeping track of odd or even.**
Suppose we use subscripts to show whether the symbol will become an odd- or even-length string: $A_0$ will eventually become an even-length string, and $A_1$ will become an odd-length string.  Let us modify the original grammar so that it uses these new symbols and respects these parity rules.

In Chomsky normal form (for a language without the empty string $\epsilon$), there are only two sorts of rules: $A\rightarrow BC$, and $A\rightarrow \mathtt{a}$, where $\mathtt{a}\in\Sigma$.

Now, if $A$ becomes a single symbol $\mathtt{a}\in \Sigma$, then $A$ has odd length.  Hence whenever the old grammar had $A\rightarrow \mathtt{a}$, a grammar that keeps track of string parity should have $A_1\rightarrow \mathtt{a}$.

As for rules of the form $A\rightarrow BC$, we know that if $A$ has even length, then $B$ and $C$ are both odd, or both even.  And if $A$ has odd length, then $B$ and $C$ are odd-and-even, or even-and-odd. Hence wherever the old grammar has $A\rightarrow BC$, a grammar that keeps track of parity should have:

\begin{align*}
A_0 &\rightarrow B_0C_0 \;\mid\; B_1C_1\\
A_1 &\rightarrow B_1C_0 \;\mid\; B_0C_1\\
\end{align*}

Finally, we need a start symbol. If $S$ was the old start symbol, we can simply put $S\rightarrow S_0 \mid S_1$ to allow the entire string to be either odd or even, without constraint.

Expanding the grammar to keep track of parity does *not* change its behavior in any way— it will still produce the same strings as usual. But keeping track of parity will make it easy to keep track of where the $z$'s belong, which is our next task.

**Enforcing alternating $z$ symbols**.

Now that we keep track of parity (odd or even length), we can easily modify the grammar to replace every other character with $z$.

For example, suppose you know that $A_1$ starts with $z$, and that $A_1\rightarrow B_0C_1$.  Then you know that $B_0$ starts with $z$. And because $B_0$ starts with $z$ and has even length, the alternating pattern of $z$'s means that you know $C_1$ must start with $z$ also.

In a similar way, given that you know whether $A$ starts or ends with $z$, the parity of $B$ and $C$ tells you whether $B$ and/or $C$ must also start with $z$. You can reason about all the possible cases.

**Putting it all together**

Let's use $A^z$ to mean a string that must start with $z$, and $A$ to mean a string that must start with an ordinary character in $\Sigma$.

Altogether, there are now four possibilities: $A_0, \;A_1, \;A_0^z, \;A_1^z$.

Our job is to convert the rules of the grammar to use the new symbols so that the grammar follows our rules about even and odd strings, and puts $\mathtt{z}$ characters where they belong.

1. Whenever the original grammar has $A\rightarrow \mathtt{a}$,  the new grammar should have $A_1\rightarrow \mathtt{a}$ and $A_1^z\rightarrow \mathtt{z}$.

   This says that only an odd-length string (subscript 1) may become a single character. If it has a superscript $z$, it must become the character $\mathtt{z}$. Otherwise, it may become the usual character $\mathtt{a}$.
2. Assuming strings in the new language must have even length and start with an ordinary symbol in $\Sigma$, the start symbol in the new grammar must be $S_0$.
3. Whenever the original grammar has $A\rightarrow BC$, the new grammar should have:
   \begin{align*}
   A_0 &\rightarrow B_0C_0 \mid B_1C_1^z\\
   A_1 &\rightarrow B_1C_0^z \mid B_0C_1\\
   A_0^z &\rightarrow B_0^zC_0^z \mid B_1^zC_1\\
   A_1^z &\rightarrow B_1^zC_0 \mid B_0^zC_1^z\\
   \end{align*}

   Once you know whether $B$ and $C$ are odd or even, and you know whether $A$ starts with $z$ or not, the alternating pattern of regular-character-followed-by-$z$ tells you whether $B$ and $C$ should start with $z$ or not.

   Knowing whether $B$ or $C$ *start* with $z$ is enough to enforce the alternating pattern of $z$'s throughout the entire string, because you will eventually recursively expand all of these nonterminal symbols to cover every character in the string.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your detailed and constructive solution.
I've added S->A_0 for each A->BC rule, that's what you meant with S_0 right?

Comment: Actually, rules like S->... are already handled by step (3). Step (2) is not about adding any new rules, just that you have to define which symbol in the grammar is the start symbol. If you define S_0 as the start symbol, the grammar behaves the right way. You can try it with a simple grammar in cnf.

Comment: Since the empty word doesn't belong to the L language, we can assume that the given grammar in Chomsky normal form is actually in Chomsky reduced form. So rules like S->... don't exist, but the context-free grammar that we are creating should have a start symbol, and I assume that for each A->BC rule in Chomsky reduced form we should add S->A_0 rule. I don't understand what you mean by defining S_0 as the start symbol, what are the rules associated with S_0? S_0 -> ??

Comment: When I wrote "S->...", what I meant was rules of the form S->BC.   You do not need to add any rules like S->A_0. The rules are all taken care of by step (3).  For example, S->BC becomes $S_0\to B_0C_0|B_1C_0^z$, and three other rules.

Comment: Remember how to use a grammar to derive a specific string like aaabbb?  Suppose your grammar is $S\to AX | AB,\;X\to SB,\; A\to a,\; B\to b.$   You start by putting down $S$. You can use the rules to successively replace it with $AX$, $aX$, $aSB$, $aSb$, $aAXb$, and so on until you get aaabbb.  This shows that aaabbb is in the grammar's language.   Whenever you derive a string from a language, you have to know what symbol to start with.  In the case of the new grammar defined in my answer, when you derive a string, you should start with the symbol $S_0$.

Comment: If you want to modify my answer so that you still start with the symbol $S$, here's what you do.  Find a fresh symbol $T$ that your old grammar doesn't use.  When you transform rules of the form $S\to BC$, transform them into rules like $T_0\to B_0C_0\mid B_1C_0^z$, $T_0^z \to B_0^z C_0^z \mid B_1^zC_0$, etc. After doing this for all the rules, you only need **one** new rule: $S\to T_0$.

Comment: Got it. Your help is much appreciated :)